# Indicatorfunction

Tags: exponential-function, characteristic-functions

Can you help me to understand why the following equation is true?
$$|e^{-x}| \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(1-e^{-x})=e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$$
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In left side indicator argument is in brackets and $|e^{-x}|$ is simply factor - correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function on the left hand side implies that

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
|e^{-x}| &\text{if $0 \lt 1 - e^{-x} \lt 1$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Solving the inequality,

$$0 \lt 1-e^{-x} \lt 1$$
$$-1 \lt e^{-x}-1 \lt 0$$
$$0 \lt e^{-x} \lt 1$$
$$ln(0) \lt -x \lt ln(1)$$
$$ -\infty \lt -x \lt 0$$
$$ 0 \lt x \lt \infty$$

Note, that for $x \in (0,1), e^{-x} \gt 0$. So we can remove the mod sign too.

Thus, We have

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-x} &\text{if $0 \lt x \lt \infty$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Which is precisely the RHS.

Comment: oh thanks a lot, i read the equation wrong and thought f(x) =
\begin{cases}
(1-e^x)|e^{-x}| &\text{if $0 \lt x \lt 1$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Comment: Oh, okay. For an indicator function, When the argument in () lies within the subscript range, its value is1. So it is a part of the indicator function, and not a separate function to be multiplied with.

Comment: Now it makes sense to me thanks:)